# How long are files kept in /var/tmp/, and how to use the directory?

Tags: linux, unix

I'm always hesitant to use /var/tmp/, because I never quite know exactly how long the files are kept there for, or even what the directory is used for. What determines when a file gets removed from /var/tmp/, and how is the directory intended to be used?

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30489/what-is-the-difference-between-tmp-and-var-tmp

Answer (score 20):

Per the [Filesystem hierarchy standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) ([FHS](http://proton.pathname.com/fhs/)), files in `/var/tmp` are to be preserved across reboots.

Per FHS-2.3:

> The /var/tmp directory is made available for programs that require temporary ﬁles or directories that are preserved between system reboots. Therefore, data stored in /var/tmp is more persistent than data in /tmp.
>
> Files and directories located in /var/tmp must not be deleted when the system is booted. Although data stored in /var/tmp is typically deleted in a site-speciﬁc manner, it is recommended that deletions occur at a less frequent interval than /tmp.

I'm not aware of any Linux distributions that automatically clean `/var/tmp`. IMO, the applications that use `/var/www` cleanup after themselves in some reasonable manner.

Comment: So by default, files in /var/tmp are not deleted automatically and are only deleted when the user manually deletes them?

Comment: I don't think that's a given as it says it's "deleted in a site-specific manner," implying that you don't have any guarantees other than it won't be deleted across a reboot. But, I think it's *likely* that *most* distributions won't delete the files in that directory but will rely on the application to clean them up.

Answer (score 16):

All RHEL-based distros clean `/var/tmp` of files older than 30 days. I don't know about other distros. Look for a cron entry that invokes tmpwatch. On Fedora/RHEL it is `/etc/cron.daily/tmpwatch`. It has a line like:

```
/usr/sbin/tmpwatch "$flags" 30d /var/tmp
```

or

```
/usr/sbin/tmpwatch 720 /var/tmp
```

(720 hours = 30 days)

Comment: To be more specific, they delete files that have not been accessed, modified or had a status change in the last 30d.

Comment: Well this is annoying.  I had followed a guide online that told me to create a script and put it in /var/tmp.   Now it's gone.